# pandas resampler agg cannot apply on list of functions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a problem with `pandas.Resampler.agg` when there is a list of functions to apply `r.apply({"price" : vwap, "qty": sum_qty, "quoteQty": sum_quoteQty})`. It always returns an error like `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'price'`. But it works fine with only one function `r.apply(vwap)`.

My dataFrame has attributes like `price`, `qty`:

[image: My data type]

I defined a list of functions to be applied on Resampler. I added some prints to debug:

[image: functions]

If I use a list of functions, then the Resampler cannot locate attributes `price` of my dataFrame:

[image: r.agg(list)]

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_939/4117684543.py in <module>
----> 1 r.apply({"price" : vwap, "qty": sum_qty, "quoteQty": sum_quoteQty})

/SSD/lime/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/resample.py in aggregate(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    332     def aggregate(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
    333 
--> 334         result = ResamplerWindowApply(self, func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs).agg()
    335         if result is None:
    336             how = func

/SSD/lime/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in agg(self)
    159 
    160         if is_dict_like(arg):
--> 161             return self.agg_dict_like()
    162         elif is_list_like(arg):
    163             # we require a list, but not a 'str'

/SSD/lime/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in agg_dict_like(self)
    433         else:
    434             # key used for column selection and output
--> 435             results = {
    436                 key: obj._gotitem(key, ndim=1).agg(how) for key, how in arg.items()
    437             }

/SSD/lime/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in <dictcomp>(.0)
    434             # key used for column selection and output
    435             results = {
--> 436                 key: obj._gotitem(key, ndim=1).agg(how) for key, how in arg.items()
    437             }
    438 

/SSD/lime/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py in aggregate(self, func, engine, engine_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
    263 
    264             try:
--> 265                 return self._python_agg_general(func, *args, **kwargs)
    266             except KeyError:
    267                 # TODO: KeyError is raised in _python_agg_general,

/SSD/lime/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py in _python_agg_general(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
   1308             try:
   1309                 # if this function is invalid for this dtype, we will ignore it.
-> 1310                 result = self.grouper.agg_series(obj, f)
   1311             except TypeError:
   1312                 warnings.warn(

/SSD/lime/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py in agg_series(self, obj, func, preserve_dtype)
   1026 
   1027         else:
-> 1028             result = self._aggregate_series_fast(obj, func)
   1029 
   1030         npvalues = lib.maybe_convert_objects(result, try_float=False)

/SSD/lime/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py in _aggregate_series_fast(self, obj, func)
   1249         #  - len(self.bins) > 0
   1250         sbg = libreduction.SeriesBinGrouper(obj, func, self.bins)
-> 1251         result, _ = sbg.get_result()
   1252         return result
   1253 

/SSD/lime/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/reduction.pyx in pandas._libs.reduction.SeriesBinGrouper.get_result()

/SSD/lime/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/reduction.pyx in pandas._libs.reduction._BaseGrouper._apply_to_group()

/SSD/lime/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py in <lambda>(x)
   1294     def _python_agg_general(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
   1295         func = com.is_builtin_func(func)
-> 1296         f = lambda x: func(x, *args, **kwargs)
   1297 
   1298         # iterate through "columns" ex exclusions to populate output dict

/tmp/ipykernel_939/2003501728.py in vwap(x)
      2     print("it's vwap")
      3     print(x)
----> 4     p = x.price
      5     print("it's p")
      6     print(p)

/SSD/lime/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5485         ):
   5486             return self[name]
-> 5487         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5488 
   5489     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'price'
```

However, it works fine with one singe function `r.apply(vwap)` and it can retrieve attributes `price` and `qty`:

[image: r.agg(f)]

The debug prints verify my hypothesis:

```
2021-09-01 00:00:00.023    1391646824
2021-09-01 00:00:00.093    1391646825
2021-09-01 00:00:00.994    1391646826
2021-09-01 00:00:00.994    1391646827
2021-09-01 00:00:00.994    1391646828
2021-09-01 00:00:00.994    1391646829
Name: trade Id, dtype: int64
it's vwap
                           trade Id     price    qty  quoteQty  isBuyerMaker
time                                                                        
2021-09-01 00:00:00.023  1391646824  47150.32  0.002     94.30          True
2021-09-01 00:00:00.093  1391646825  47150.33  0.002     94.30         False
2021-09-01 00:00:00.994  1391646826  47150.33  0.021    990.15         False
2021-09-01 00:00:00.994  1391646827  47150.33  0.021    990.15         False
2021-09-01 00:00:00.994  1391646828  47152.97  0.002     94.30         False
2021-09-01 00:00:00.994  1391646829  47153.48  0.006    282.92         False
it's p
time
2021-09-01 00:00:00.023    47150.32
2021-09-01 00:00:00.093    47150.33
2021-09-01 00:00:00.994    47150.33
2021-09-01 00:00:00.994    47150.33
2021-09-01 00:00:00.994    47152.97
2021-09-01 00:00:00.994    47153.48
Name: price, dtype: float64
it's q
time
2021-09-01 00:00:00.023    0.002
2021-09-01 00:00:00.093    0.002
2021-09-01 00:00:00.994    0.021
2021-09-01 00:00:00.994    0.021
2021-09-01 00:00:00.994    0.002
2021-09-01 00:00:00.994    0.006
Name: qty, dtype: float64
it's vwap
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [trade Id, price, qty, quoteQty, isBuyerMaker]
Index: []
it's p
Series([], Name: price, dtype: float64)
it's q
Series([], Name: qty, dtype: float64)
it's vwap
                           trade Id     price    qty  quoteQty  isBuyerMaker
time                                                                        
2021-09-01 00:00:02.050  1391646830  47153.47  0.006    282.92          True
2021-09-01 00:00:02.889  1391646831  47153.47  0.054   2546.28          True
2021-09-01 00:00:02.889  1391646832  47153.47  0.050   2357.67          True
2021-09-01 00:00:02.889  1391646833  47153.47  0.050   2357.67          True
it's p
time
2021-09-01 00:00:02.050    47153.47
2021-09-01 00:00:02.889    47153.47
2021-09-01 00:00:02.889    47153.47
2021-09-01 00:00:02.889    47153.47
Name: price, dtype: float64
it's q
time
2021-09-01 00:00:02.050    0.006
2021-09-01 00:00:02.889    0.054
2021-09-01 00:00:02.889    0.050
2021-09-01 00:00:02.889    0.050
Name: qty, dtype: float64
```

But when I try the example of official documentation, everything works fine even with a list of functions:

[image: doc1]
[image: doc2]

So I really have no idea about where the problem is...

Comment: Just shooting here: try using brackets indexing notation, rather than dot notation, when accessing cols, e.g. `x['price']` instead of `x.price`, etc. I had a problem once with the dot notation...

Comment: @user17242583 Now it gets a `KeyError: 'price'` instead of AttributeError...

Comment: Will you please add the code to create `r` to the question?

Comment: @user17242583 It is very standard: `r = csv.head(10).resample('1s', label='right')` and the result is the same if I remove `label='right'`.

Answer (score 0):

Oh wait.

The hint is in the error message:

```
'Series' object has no attribute 'price'
```

It's because the `x` that your `vwap` function is being called with is a `Series`. It's the `price` column, because that's what you said `vwap` should get! (`{"price": vwap, ...}`)

By default, `apply()` goes column-wise, like most other functions. If you want to `apply()` row-wise, using `apply(..., axis=1)`.

You'll need to change around your dict passed to `apply()` probably, but that should get you going again :)

Comment: I did try `apply(..., axis=1)` and the error message is the same... I am not very sure how to change my dict because I indeed need to operate on 2 columns.

Comment: The point is I need x to be a DataFrame as the case of `r.apply(vwap)` but I see no option except calling `r.apply(func)` multiple times for each column in the result.